# Show date range start date and end date

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table with a start and end date. I want to output all records that fall within a range. The range would be from 2023-03-30 to 2023-04-15. All records that are within the time window need to be output, including records that start earlier and end later.

```
ID   Start       End
1    2023-02-01  2023-06-15
2    2023-03-24  2023-04-12
3    2023-04-10  2023-04-20
4    2023-04-01  2023-04-05
5    2023-03-10  2023-03-28
6    2023-04-16  2023-04-20
7    2023-03-31  2023-04-15
8    2023-03-30  2023-04-15
9    2023-04-15  2023-04-20
10   2023-04-16  2023-04-20
```

```
SET @startDay = '2023-03-30';
SET @LastDay = '2023-04-15';
SELECT
  ID,
  Start,
  End
From tbl
WHERE (Start <= @startDay AND End >= @LastDay)
   OR (Start >= @startDay AND End <= @LastDay)
```

A query would show records 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9 but not 5, 6, 10.
Doesn't work unfortunately. How would I have to change the query?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get rows where any part of the time period appears in your range, then you need to check that the end date is *after* the start time and the start date is *before* the end date.

```sql
SET @StartDay = '2023-03-30';
SET @LastDay = '2023-04-15';
SELECT ID,
       Start,
       [End] --End is a reserved keyword, it should not be used for object/column names
FROM dbo.tbl
WHERE [End] >= @StartDay --End is a reserved keyword, it should not be used for object/column names
  AND Start <= @LastDay;
```

Comment: does not work. No records are output.

Comment: After I fix the delimit identifying (I strongly recommend against using reserved keywords for object/column names), it works fine, @thomas-99 : [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QdGMkVSk)

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to wrap your column name `end` in double quotation marks to declare that it is not used as a keyword.

Try this

```
DECLARE @start_date DATE = '2023-03-30';
DECLARE @end_date DATE = '2023-04-15';

SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE "End" >= @start_date
  AND Start <= @end_Date;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lsJCG5Ez)